# Nvarchar showing as question marks in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i have the following stored procedure.

```
alter proc testUpdate
@ku nvarchar(255),
@tablename nvarchar(50)
as
declare @query nvarchar(max)

SET @query = 'UPDATE '+@tablename+' SET ku = @ku WHERE id = 1'

PRINT(@query)

EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@ku nvarchar(255), @tablename nvarchar(50)', @ku, @tablename
```

when the query executes the outcome of @ku is ??? if using Arabic letters. I know if i pass the value with the N' prefix to the stored procedure, then there will be no issues.

but is there a way to change that inside the stored procedure?

thanks

Comment: Why are you using `sys.sp_executesql` here, when there's nothing dynamic about your query?

Comment: Where is `@ky` defined and set? Question marks suggest it's not `nvarchar` or the value is set to a literal without the `N' prefix.

Comment: this is a test query, in my original query the ku is defined and the table name is dynamic. @Larnu

Comment: Then show us a more representative query, @ahmadnoori . I would not be surprised you have hidden the error from us, due to over oversimplification. Give us an [mre].

Comment: Alright, done. @Larnu

Comment: Careful, that's wide open to injection. You should be quoting your object names properly, That doesn't repro the problem though. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e9045b74664d133bee4ae518cebf3c6f)

Comment: i'm puzzled to why it is doing that? could it be a collation problem? i have used the same collation forever now and never faced this problem @Larnu

Comment: yep, could be collation related. If you don't have the `N` prefix then string literals are restricted to what ever the 256 characters are that are in the code page for the database's default collation. If this is something like `Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS` then this will support arabic characters. If it is something like `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI` then it won't.

Comment: This is why it's really important you give us a [mre], @ahmadnoori .

Comment: i'm literally executing the query in the question. the same way you did. @Larnu

Answer (score 1):

When setting the value of an `NVARCHAR` variable, you **must** precede the string literal with a `N` - try this:

```
DECLRAE @query nvarchar(max)

SET @query = N'UPDATE tblCountry SET ku = @ku WHERE id = 1'

PRINT(@query)

EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@ku nvarchar(255)', @ku
```

The `N` before the string literal to set the `@query` variable indicates **Unicode** string literal. Otherwise, the contents of the string literal is converted back to `VARCHAR` (non-Unicode)